# Error, then black screen after wubi 11.10

Tags: 11.10, windows, wubi

I have this laptop with Windows 7 :
http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=LX-PXN02-147-DT

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 via Wubi and when I boot intu Ubuntu using the boot up menu, I get this error:

```
Try (hd 0,0) NTFS5: No wubildr
Try (hd 0,1) NTFS5: No wubildr
Try (hd 0,2) NTFS5: Error: "prefix" not set.
```

Then, I get a blank purple screen, which turns completely black and stays there.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this is going to solve your problem, but if I face this situation, my first shot is to:

- Fully de-install Wubi,
- Turn off Windows completely (pull it out from power source for at least 10 seconds, in your case take off the battery too for at least 30 seconds),
- reboot,
- re-install Wubi from zero.

My first try with Wubi failed too; with other hardware configuration. A good search in Google usually finds a good solution for this situation too.